# Bearing features (2RS versus 2RSH)

Tags: lubrication, bearing, wheel-bearing

I have done sufficient googling to discover that a -2RS bearing is one with two rubber seals. I haven't ascertained much beyond that. For an application currently using a 2RSH bearing, can I replace it with a 2RS bearing? When is the answer yes, and when is the answer no? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the stack. I know you've already mentioned that you're talking about a application using one type of bearing, but is this for a particular year/make/model? If so, please add that info. If it's a more theoretical question, that's fine too, but do try to be as specific as possible so we're not completely open to opinion or guessing. ;) good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per this dictionary](http://www.skf.com/group/products/bearings-units-housings/ball-bearings/principles/bearing-basics/basic-bearing-designation-system/prefixes-and-suffixes/suffixes-p-s/index.html) the RS and RSH parts mean the same thing. They mean

> Contact seal made of acrylonitrile-butadiene rubber (NRB)...

That would make it seem as though different manufacturers may use different acronyms for the same thing. *If* that is really the case then you can totally interchange the 2. *However*, I'm not super-familiar with the nomenclature of wheel bearings, and they could mean something different.

If anyone here knows with certainty that the above is right or wrong, let me know. But from what I can scrounge up it appears that they are completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to run into this old question through a search engine. I found the answer so I will share it. The two are almost the same and for most intents and purposes interchangeable, they are of the same type and material. 2RSH is a slightly better seal, at the cost of a bit more friction. Depending on the application, you may prefer one or the other. Source (in Dutch) https://duursma.nl/blog/57-welke-afdichting-kies-ik-bij-een-groefkogellager